# How to use typescript generic type as an object key

Tags: typescript, generics

```
function myFunc<T extends string>(key: T): Record<T, string> {
        return { [key]: 'asdf' };
    }
```

I get an error:

```
Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<T, string>'.ts(2322)
```

How to get rid of the error and enable auto-completion on the returned object?

P.S. Without using `return { [key]: 'asdf' } as Record<T, string>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the signature into an overload:

```
function myFunc<T extends string>(key: T): Record<T, string>;
function myFunc(key: string) {
    return { [key]: 'asdf' };
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFwQDwBVECmAHlAWACYDOilUATjGAOYB8AFANYGoBciuASj4AlAhDh1yeADQ16jVgG4AsAChQkWAhQYsnbn1oNmAxAG81iK4joEoIOkjOIA2l1QBdPgHIAhpXJgb0QAXxVVEKA)